# Is there an alternative to Class User in Google Apps Script to use in this context?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want some menus of a same spreadsheet to be shown to some of the users of that spreadsheet, but not for others. 
The menus are invocated by the "onOpen" trigger. But there is a restriction to get the user's email when you use this trigger, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user). Is there some alternative in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restriction applies to simple trigger called `onOpen`, it you use an installable trigger and if you're inside a domain you should be able to do what you want.

Please update here if it works (for info), thanks.

Comment: See also this other post, it might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572851/google-sheets-session-geteffectiveuser-returns-wrong-values-twice

Comment: Hi, @Sergeinsas, I'm not inside a domain. And I'm having some trouble with installable trigger. Could you point me some question or simple code with a installable trigger? PS - Just starting reading your book. It'll give me a better foundation knowledge in GAS. And I'm enjoying your writing!